# Initializing powershell module variables that will be exported

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble understanding why I cannot achieve the following:

Create a set of variables in a module.
Have a function in the module do something and update the parent scope variable with the changed value.
Import the Module into a script that calls the same function and have the updated value available to the script that imported the module.

For example 
Module Lib has the following:

```
$psVarx = -1

function Init {

   $psVarx = 2
   $script:psVarx = $psVarx
}
```

`Export-Member -variable $psVarx`

And the script using the module has the following:

```
Import-Module Lib -Force

Init

"psVarx is {0}" -f $psVarx
```

The output received is

`psVarx is -1`

The question is if I updated the script scoped copy of the variable in the module, why does the script using the module not see the updated value of the variable?  I am pretty sure the issue has to do with scoping.  What am I missing here?

What is the recommended method for initializing module variables in the situation where the module has work it needs to do to initialize itself and set variables that then should be made available to the code that is Importing the module?

In this particular case I have dozens of variables that I would like to initialize within a module and then export the newly initialized values.

Comment: Given the code you posted, your results look like what I'd expect. Your code never calls the `Init` function, so the only code that ever sets `$psVarx` is the `$psVarx = -1` line.

Comment: My mistake, the code I actually have does call the Init function.  I will see if I can update the post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell V3 the following works:

```
$psVarx = -1

function Init {

   $psVarx = 2
   $script:psVarx = $psVarx
}
Export-ModuleMember -variable psVarx -Function init
```

Notice that `psVarx` (not `$psVarx`) is passed to `Export-modulemember` (not Export-Member). Also `Init` is specified.